# How to test a rails PORO called from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller

I have extracted part of my Foos controller into a new rails model to perform the action:

**foos_controller.rb**

```
class FoosController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :js

  def create
    @foo = current_user.do_something(@bar)
    actioned_bar = ActionedBar.new(@bar)
    actioned_bar.create
    respond_with @bar
  end
```

**actioned_bar.rb**

```
class ActionedBar
  def initialize(bar)
    @bar = bar
  end

  def create
    if @bar.check?
      # do something
    end
  end
end
```

I got it working first but now I'm trying to back-fill the rspec controller tests.

I'll be testing the various model methods and will be doing a feature test to make sure it's ok from that point of view but I would like to add a test to make sure the new actioned_bar model is called from the foos controller with @bar.

I know in rspec you can test that something `receives` something `with` some `arguments` but I'm struggling to get this to work.

```
    it "calls ActionedBar.new(bar)" do
      bar = create(:bar)
      expect(ActionedBar).to receive(:new)

      xhr :post, :create, bar_id: bar.id
    end
```

This doesn't work though, the console reports:

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `create' for nil:NilClass
```

which is strange because it only does this when I use `expect(ActionedBar).to receive(:new)`, the rest of the controller tests work fine.

If I try to do:

```
    it "calls ActionedBar.new(bar)" do
      bar = create(:bar)
      actioned_bar = ActionedBar.new(bar)
      expect(actioned_bar).to receive(:create).with(no_args)

      xhr :post, :create, bar_id: bar.id
    end
```

the console says:

```
(#<ActionedBar:0xc8f9f74>).create(no args)
       expected: 1 time with no arguments
       received: 0 times with no arguments
```

If I do a `put` in the controller whilst running the test; for some reason this test causes the actioned_bar in the controller to be output as `nil` but fine for all the other controller tests.

Is there any way I can test that ActionedBar is being called in this controller spec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `expect_any_instance_of(ActionedBar).to receive(:create)`, because instance in spec and in controller are different instances.

If you want to use original object, you can use `expect(ActionedBar).to receive(:new).and_call_original` (without that `#new` just will return nil and you'll get `NoMethodError`).

Comment: Thanks Maxim Khan-Magomedov, both these tests worked fine. I also added an additional test as max suggests in his answer to ensure actioned bar is actually performed.

Answer (score 0):

The core problem is that `actioned_bar` in your spec in is not going to be the the same instance of `ActionedBar` that is in your controller. Thus the spec will always fail.

Instead you need to have ActionedBar return a double when new is called:

```
it "calls ActionedBar.new(bar)" do
  bar = create(:bar)
  actioned_bar = instance_double("ActionedBar")
  allow(ActionedBar).to receive(:new).and_return(actioned_bar)
  expect(actioned_bar).to receive(:create).with(no_args)
  xhr :post, :create, bar_id: bar.id
end
```

However I generally consider this kind of test a code smell - its ok to mock out external collaborators and set expectations that you are passing the correct messages. But your might want to consider if your are testing  the details of how your controller does its job and not the actual behavior.

I find it better to setup a spec which calls the controller action and set expectations on what how it for example changes the database state or how it effects the response.

Comment: Thanks. I've gone with Maxim Khan-Magomedov's answer because as yet I'm not a massive fan of using doubles, but I have added an extra test as you suggested to ensure that the action is actually performed.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a double ActionedBar which is returned by the ActionedBar.new call as this instance is different to the one used in the controller.

```
describe "#create" do
  let(:actioned_bar) { double(ActionedBar) }
  let(:bar) { double(Bar) }

  it "calls ActionedBar.new(bar)" do
    expect(ActionedBar).to receive(:new).with(bar).and_returns(actioned_bar)
    expect(actioned_bar).to receive(:create)

    xhr :post, :create, bar_id: bar.id
  end
end
```